# What is the vote limit?

Tags: discussion, support, votes

What is the limit to the number of votes one can cast per day? I've never hit this limit on SO, but I appear to have hit it here today (well, it says I have 1 vote left). I've probably cast ~20 votes in the last 24 hours. If the vote limit is ~20, should it be raised?

(If it isn't then I have an inkling of why I might have hit the limit, I cast a ton of downvotes on a thread where the poster had posted a bunch of times to rep-whore)

Comment: I'm hitting the vote limit quite often too, we might want to slightly increase it to 40 or 50, but not more...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [30 votes a day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits-in-stackoverflow), and it really shouldn't be raised. Limits are in place to prevent abuse: SOIC has ostensibly thought a lot about what the limits should be and why they're necessary.

Further discussion: [Why are there voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/why-are-there-voting-limits)